# Why sql_variant datatype is not common in development?

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes, sql-variant

I was looking at system tables and saw `sql_variant` datatype for some of the columns. I have never seen any column with `sql_variant` datatype in production databases. Is there any reason for this.

Comment: Perhaps due to the overhead of having to explicitly cast to a different datatype in order to compare to other columns/values?

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick: Using sql_variant at all](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type): *Several external tools don't support it (e.g. entity framework), some providers like ODBC automatically convert the values to NVARCHAR(4000), and you can't use the column in the definition of a computed column.  It also can't be part of a primary or foreign key, nor can you use wildcard operators such as LIKE.  And even if you only store numbers, you cannot use operators like SUM(), MAX(), addition or subtraction.*

Comment: From a relational purists' perspective, each column should contain data of the same type. `sql_variant` works away from this. Not that I'm claiming the all or even most SQL developers *are* relational purists...

Comment: Then why microsoft introduced sql_variant data type. Is it just to make database open for changes?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well they should be :)

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770315/using-anydata-sql-variant-in-fact-table/9770625#9770625